# How do I get a particular part of a string?

Tags: c, string, file

I'm trying to build a program that gets a declaration from the user
(for example: `int x` or `char idan`) and then opens a new file, and writes to it the size that will be needed to allocate the memory for the declaration.

I got almost everything done, even a case when a user declaration is filled with spaces, but I'm having a hard time with getting the string of the variable name.

I want to create a function that will copy to a new string called `var_name` only the variable name and will return it. How can I do that?

*Update - 5/9/18

hey i found a way to copy only part of the string:

```
strncpy(var_name, &declaration[7], count);
var_name[count + 1] = '\0';
```

now when im returning var_name (var_name its a string)
it is returns allright,but when i send it to another function it becomes garbage...

Comment: in which language/environment do you want to do this?

Comment: in C,Visual studio

Comment: Do you mean you are requested to write code that parses an arbitrary C variable declaration?

Comment: It's most likely you declared `var_name` as a local variable in some function, meaning it's allocated on the stack (on any common, modern C--pedants can step off).  More likely you need to allocate it on the heap using `malloc()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `strncpy`, it does not do what you think: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

In your case, assuming `var_name` is large enough, at least `count + 1` bytes, a simple call to `memcpy(var_name, declaration + 7, count)` would be better.

You probably make another mistake in your code (which ou did not post): you cannot return the address of a local array, accessing its contents after returning has undefined behavior.

Here is a simple function you can use to allocate and copy a portion of a string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *substr(const char *s, size_t pos, size_t len) {
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p) {
        memcpy(p, s + pos, len);
        p[len] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

Use it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *p1 = substr("Hello world\n", 0, 5);
    char *p2 = substr("Hello world\n", 6, 5);
    printf("%s %s\n", p1, p2);
    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    return 0;
}
```